# Nginx proxy_pass and redirect

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I tried to clean up my urls on my reverse proxy nginx config. My config looks like this

```
upstream blog {
    ip:port;
}
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.tdl www.domain.tdl;

        rewrite ^/index.html$ / redirect;
        rewrite ^(/.+)/index.html$ $1 redirect;

        if ($request_uri ~* ".html") {
            rewrite (?i)^(.*)/(.*)\.html $1/$2 redirect;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://blog;
        }
}
```

As long as the port in my blog upsteam is 80 everything works fine. But if I change that to something else nginx will try to redirect my requests to domain.tdl:port which obviously doesn't work. I tired many combinations of proxy_set_header and proxy_redirect but nothing works for me.

As requested a bit more details all outputs are from `curl -Lv`:

I set ip:port to ip:8000

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://blog:8000/archiv/
```

I set proxy_pass to `http://blog http://domain.tdl`

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://domain.tdl/:8000/archiv/
```

I set ip:80

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://domain.tdl/archiv/
```

Has anyone a idea why this happens or how I can fix that?

Comment: What do you want the input, output pair be and what it is now? I'm having hard time understanding what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Long story short, my redirects don't work if the upstream has something else than port 80

Comment: You probably shouldn't make long story short. Quite the opposite. If your upstream is set like `upstream blog {
    ip:8888;
}` What URL do you enter and what exactly happens (include error message, response code, whatever), or what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Fox sorry I misunderstood you, I updated the question now with more details

Comment: No problem. Just please, tell me the URL you used with the `curl`. Thanks.